# Why does enabling secured shared memory slow site load speeds?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, ubuntu-18.04

I set up a new droplet with Digital Ocean and I've been enjoying it.  One thing I noticed was that my sites were loading nearly twice as fast.  I've been looking into securing the server, mainly the basics (forcing SSH login, ufw firewall, etc).  I followed [this guide](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-harden-ubuntu-server-16-04-security-in-five-steps/) yesterday.  I looked at the load times for my sites and noticed that they nearly doubled.  I went back undoing changes until they returned to the faster speeds.  The last one I changed was disabling secured shared memory.

With secure shared memory disabled, my site load times are 350-450ms.  With it enabled they shoot up to 800ms to 1.2s.  Is this normal for enabling secured shared memory?  If so, is the trade off worth it, or are there better alternatives?

I'm on apache 2.4, ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I don't think anyone of us can give any direct answer to "is the trade off worth it". Only you know the value of your data and only you can estimate the effect of load time to your bottom line. Then you also need to have some estimate of how likely a compromise is with and without this feature. Only analysing these facts will lead you to understanding what the possible effect to your bottom line is with this setting.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I didn't mean "is it worth it" in the broad sense. As an example, the article I linked shows how to prevent "IP spoofing". From my testing and googling, the method they list is deprecated, and some people say Google already prevents it, so it "wouldn't be worth it" given reasonable consideration of those facts for any person. Are there alternatives that give the same effect without the trade off, is it still a common practice, etc.